# File.Exists returns false,Process.Start() can't start the file,But it actually exists

Tags: c#, .net, windows, windows-sandbox

Note : Windows Sandbox is enabled on my computer.

```
Console.WriteLine(File.Exists(@"C:\Windows\system32\WindowsSandbox.exe"));
Console.WriteLine(new FileInfo(@"C:\Windows\system32\WindowsSandbox.exe").Exists);
```

Running the above code in `C# Interactive`(VS is not in admin mode):

```
True
True
```

However , when I run it in a console application,
(both admin mode and non-admin mode).The results are always false.

```
False
False
```

I tried `Process.Start(@"C:\Windows\system32\WindowsSandbox.exe")`,
the console application failed(admin and non-admin) but the C# interactive succeeded.

In powershell,`C:\Windows\system32\WindowsSandbox.exe` successfully started the Windows Sandbox.
In explorer(system32 folder):
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZJEx.png)

Could anyone explain why this could happen?

Comment: Is Window Sandbox set to run a Admin?

Comment: I assume you're using 64-bit Windows?  If so, do you have a `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsSandbox.exe` and is the console application targeting 32-bit?

Comment: Set processStartInfo.Verb to "runas" didn't solve the problem.@jdweng

Comment: I'm using 64-bit windows,but there's no WindowsSandbox.exe in SysWOW64 in explorer.@BACON

Comment: On 64-bit Windows, unless you go out of your way to run the 32-bit versions, Explorer and PowerShell will be 64-bit processes and will, therefore, run system executables from the 64-bit system directory, `system32`.  If your application is 32-bit it would redirect the path you specify to the 32-bit system directory, `SysWOW64`.  Try changing your path from `WindowsSandbox.exe` to something like `calc.exe` or `notepad.exe`, both of which definitely exist in both `system32` and `SysWOW64`, and see if it works.  I suspect it will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Windows Sandbox, but it sounds like this is an architecture issue.

On 64-bit Windows, `C:\Windows\system32` is the 64-bit system directory.  Explorer and PowerShell, which you say can both see `C:\Windows\system32\WindowsSandbox.exe`, will be 64-bit processes unless you go out of your way to run the 32-bit versions.

In a 32-bit application, the path `C:\Windows\system32` gets [redirected](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/winprog64/file-system-redirector) to the 32-bit system directory, `C:\Windows\SysWOW64`.  Since you say you don't have a `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsSandbox.exe` file, nor can your application see (what it thinks is) a `C:\Windows\system32\WindowsSandbox.exe` file, that suggests that your application is built targeting 32-bit.

So, the problem is there is no 32-bit version of `Windows Sandbox` for your 32-bit application to run.  When you change the path to `calc.exe` or `notepad.exe` your same code works because Windows provides both 32- and 64-bit versions of those executables.  To get your application to run the 64-bit `WindowsSandbox.exe`, you can either...

- Build it targeting 64-bit, or better yet...
- Have it execute the path `C:\Windows\sysnative\WindowsSandbox.exe`.  `sysnative` is a special alias that allows 32-bit applications to reference the native (64-bit) system directory without redirection.

As for why Visual Studio is able to see `C:\Windows\system32\WindowsSandbox.exe`, I can't really explain that.  It would depend on what version you're using, but it's my understanding that continues to be a 32-bit application, although it would make sense that some components are 64-bit.  As for whether components such as the debugger would run as the same architecture as the *OS* or the *application* being built, I really don't know.

Comment: Might be worth linking to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/file-system-redirector) and mentioning `sysnative`

Comment: Thanks, @Damien_The_Unbeliever.  I incorporated that into my answer.

Answer (score 3):

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists.aspx):

> The Exists method returns false if any error occurs while trying to
>   determine if the specified file exists. This can occur in situations
>   that raise exceptions such as passing a file name with invalid
>   characters or too many characters, a failing or missing disk, or ***if
>   the caller does not have permission to read the file.***

One way of seeing what's happening is to just try to read the file (e.g. with File.OpenRead). I'd be surprised if that succeeds - but if it fails, the exception should give you more information. Also check from the call what identity is used when running the command (i.e. `cmd whoami`, etc.)

Comment: It got FileNotFoundException,in admin mode.But I'm interested why C# interactive could do it.